# If Then Else syntax in MS SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables that I need to pull data from,  that data is dependant on the results from the other tables,  so I am trying to use an if then else structure and am getting syntax errors.  I may be over my head as far as SQL expertise goes.  I generate a syntax error near the first if and subsequently near each then.   Is this a simple syntax error or am I trying to do something MS SQL 2000 is incapable of handling?

Thank you for your input.

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
Go
Begin
Declare @vCasinoName varchar(35)
select @vCasinoName = Description from Gen_Casino
Create Table #AG_Report
(Slotnumber int,
 SRID varchar(30), 
SerialNumber varchar(15),
CAsset varchar(30),
Mfr varchar(15),
Denomination numeric(12, 2),
Description varchar(30),
Par real,
EPROMID varchar(15),
EPROMID2 varchar(15),
EPROMIDXL varchar(30),
Jurisdiction varchar(30),
Bios varchar(30),
BootChip varchar(30),
VersionChip varchar(30),
CasinoName varchar(35),
)
insert into #AG_Report
select  s.SlotNumber, 
    s.SerialNumber,
    m.Manufacturer,
s.Denomination,
s.Description,
s.Par,
s.EPROMID,
s.EPROMID2,
if (CF.FieldID = 6) 
        BEGIN
        CF.Value as SRID,
        END
            else if (CF.FieldID = 7)
            BEGIN
            CF.Value as CAsset,
            END
                else if (CF.FieldID = 9)
                BEGIN
                else if (CF.FieldID = 9)
                BEGIN
                CF.value as EPROMIDXL,
                    else if (CF.FieldID = 13)
                    BEGIN
                    CF.Value as Jurisdiction,
                    END
                        else if (CF.FieldID = 11)
                        BEGIN
                        CF.Value as Bios,
                        END
                            else if (CF.FieldID = 12)
                            BEGIN
                            CF.Value as BootChip,
                            END
                                else if (CF.FieldID = 14)
                                BEGIN
                                CF.Value as VersionChip,
                                END
from CDS_Slotmast S, BB_SlotMastCustomField CF,BB_Mfr M,
where S.SlotMast_id = CF.SlotMast_ID
and CF.Revision = S.Revision
and S.Active = "Y"
order by s.Denomination, s,SlotNumber
Select * from #AG_Report
End
```

Comment: There is an `IF` _statement_ and a `CASE` _expression_. Have a look at `CASE`.

Comment: What do you think the IF logic should be doing?  If inserting, the alias of the fields you're selecting doesn't matter, and that's all you're changing since it's all the `CF.Value` field.

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what @HABO said, instead if this within a select statement:

```
if (CF.FieldID = 6) 
        BEGIN
        CF.Value as SRID,
        END
            else if (CF.FieldID = 7)
```

Try this:

```
CASE 
    WHEN (CF.FieldID = 6) THEN 'SRID' --You can return a value from a field or have another case statement here if you need to.
    WHEN (CF.FieldID = 7)
    ...Continue your code  
    ELSE
    ...If you want an ELSE    
    END --End the case statement
```

Comment: `Goat CO`'s comment is valid as well. The whole logic is pointless when using `INSERT`.

Comment: I think they were just completely lost and didn't know what they were writting ;-)  I have edited my code slightly to not set a value in the `then` but return a string (as an example).

Answer (score 0):

Using IF inside a SELECT statement is not possible in SQL Server. Instead you can use CASE statement. You can you use nested case also, case inside WHEN

Answer (score 0):

The case statement is the right approach to an IF inside a select, but it looks like from your statement, that regardless of the value of CF.FieldID you are always returning CF.Value, but trying to return a different alias for the column.  You can't really do that - the column alias needs to be the same for every row in the result set.  But in terms of returning the data, you could just include CF.FieldID and CF.Value in the result set and then let application code do the work.